# Conditional PDF of X given that X<1/Y and Y=y, if X and Y are i.i.d. and exponentially distributed

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have two independent random variables X and Y, with exponential probability density functions: $f_X(w)=f_Y(w)=\lambda e^{-\lambda w}$. I want to calculate the conditional pdf of $X$ given that the event $A:X<1/Y$ occurs and that $Y=y$. \begin{equation*}f_X(x|A,Y=y)\end{equation*}
I thought about the following approach, but it doesn't seem right to me:
\begin{equation*}
f_X(x|A,Y=y)=\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y<1/x)}{f_Y(y<1/x)}
\end{equation*}
Furthermore, I struggle to compute the joint distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\mathsf P(X\in B\mid X<1/Y,Y=y)=\mathsf P(X\in B\mid X<1/y,Y=y)=\mathsf P(X\in B\mid X<1/y)$

The last equality because $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

And to determine the PDF of $X$ that is conditional wrt event $\{X<1/y\}$ you only need the original PDF of $X$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Am I then right with the assumption that $P(X\in B | X<1/y)=\int_0^\infty \int_0^{1/y}f_X(x)f_X(x)\partial x \partial x$ which would result in $\int_0^\infty \int_0^{1/y}\lambda^2e^{-2\lambda x}$?

Comment: At LHS there is set $B$ mentioned and at RHS there is not. So cannot be okay. To find conditional PDF find an expression in $x$ for $P(X\leq x\mid X<1/y)$ (i.e. conditional CDF) and differentiate to find conditional PDF.

Comment: Sorry, but I am stuck here. How can I find such an expression in x? For $P(X < x| X<1/y)$ it would result in $\int_0^x \int_0^{1/y} f_X(x)f_X(x)\partial x \partial x$?

Comment: First find the CDF of $X$ as an expression in $x$ without any integral signs in it. Based on that find conditional CDF  (see my former comment) on base of $P(A|B)=P(A\cap   B)/P(B)$. Then differentiate to get conditional PDF.

Comment: Ok If I assume $P(X\geq t |X<1/y)$ I can calculate $P(B \cap A)=\int_t^{1/y}\lambda e^{-\lambda w}=e^{-\lambda t}-e^{-\lambda/y}$ resulting in $P(B|A)=\frac{e^{-\lambda t}-e^{-\lambda/y}}{1-e^{-\lambda/y}}$. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Almost. What I meant is $P(X\leq x\mid X<1/y)=P(X\leq x\wedge X<1/y)/P(X<1/y)=(1-e^{-\lambda x})/(1-e^{-\lambda/y})$ if $0<x<1/\lambda$ and $=1$ if $X\geq1/\lambda$ and $=0$ if $x\leq0$. This is the conditional CDF and its derivative (wrt $x$) is the conditional PDF.